# UIGestureRecognizers interfering with UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, open-source

I'm working on an OpenSource Magazine Engine that you can look at on GitHub:

https://github.com/interactivenyc/Defrag

I've set up a UIToolbar in a UIView I've called MenuPanel. For some reason the UIBarButtonItems in the UIToolbar aren't calling their actions properly.  Here is the syntax I'm using for the buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];
```

What *is* happening is that anywhere I click on my screen, the UITapGestureRecognizer declared in my main UIViewController is being called instead.  This gets setup in this block of code in my main UIViewController:

```
- (void)setupGestureRecognizers {

//NSLog(@"setupGestureRecognizer NEW");

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer;

swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];

swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];

swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];

swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;

tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
}
```

I'm sure I have something pretty basic conceptually wrong with how I'm trying to do this.  Can someone tell me how I can fix this problem?

For reference, you can see my main DefragViewController: UIViewController here:

**https://gist.github.com/1431722**

And my MenuPanel: UIView here:

**gist.github.com/1431728**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own question.

I had to tell my UIViewController to ignore touches from any UIToolbar like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

    //ignore any touches from a UIToolbar

    if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure and mark your answer as accepted so that others will know there is a solution.